# In which article did Nigel Short retract from having played online vs Fischer?

Tags: history, famous-players, fischer, famous-moves

I read a [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/nigelshortchess/status/1342156458859896832) by Nigel Short mentioning his retraction, but I can't find it.

[image: Short's tweett]

Comment: The beauty of Twitter is that you can actually ask him about it: https://twitter.com/gerwindegroot/status/1342861267833384961 Let's hope he responds ...

Comment: Related: [Who did Nigel Short really play on the ICC in 2001 when he thought he was playing Fischer?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1236/17823)

Comment: Thanks, @Glorfindel. So it seems the retraction was made on [The Sunday Telegraph](telegraph.co.uk). I made a couple searches ("Fischer online Acevedo site:telegraph.co.uk", and similar ones) but with not much success. Also, the Telegraph needs a subscription to read its content. It offers a one month free trial, but you're asked your credit card number, and that info I'm not going to provide just for satisfying my curiosity.

Comment: Related: http://web.archive.org/web/20210102124726/https://www.telegraph.co.uk/comment/4265656/Fischer-caught-out.html

Answer (score 2):

I thought it was in New In Chess where he was writing a column for a long time,
but according to chessbase.com it was in Telegraph:

https://en.chessbase.com/post/the-third-coming-of-bobby-fischer-

Comment: Nope. Chessbase is talking about the article Short published his original statement in, *not* the retraction

Comment: yes, and it was published in the Telegraph mag,

Comment: The question asks about the retraction. Your answer talks about the original post